# Angular ngrx + Firebase OAuth action called but effect not

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

i have an issue with my oauth setup, when i logout with this effect:

```
@Effect()
  logout:  Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType(UserActions.LOGOUT)
    .switchMap(() => Observable.of(this.afAuth.auth.signOut()))
    .map(() => new UserActions.GetUser())
    .catch(err => Observable.of(new UserActions.AuthError({error: err.message})));
```

Everything works fine and the `UserActions.GetUser()` is being called. Now if i try to log in with this effect and this firebase auth function:

```
@Effect()
  googleLogin: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType(UserActions.GOOGLE_LOGIN)
    .switchMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(this.loginWithGoogle()))
    .map(() => new UserActions.GetUser())
    .catch(err => Observable.of(new UserActions.AuthError({error: err.message})));

private loginWithGoogle() {
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}
```

The new `UserActions.GetUser()` is called and i can see it in the Redux DevTools, but the actual effect is not called, i put a lot of console.log's in there to see if i did something wrong in the function, but it isn't called at all and also i have a `catch` in the `GetUser`, but that's also not triggering.

Is there some issue with firebase in this case or am i stupid?

Actions:

[image: Dispatched Actions]

Get User effect:

```
@Effect()
  getUser: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType(UserActions.GET_USER)
    .switchMap(() => {
      console.log('test'); // <-- Not called
      return this.afAuth.authState;
    })
    .map(()=> {
      return new UserActions.Authenticated();
    });
```

** **EDIT 1**

I made a new observation: When there is no internet connection anymore, so firebase loads from local, it actually works, somehow there is an issue with the connection to the firebase database

Comment: Can you add the dispatched actions log when running your test scenario to your question ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun Added it

Comment: Is the "Get user" action that you want to catch in some effect ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun The "Get user" action is what loads the user from my database with the data given from firebase. But the effect of this action is not called. Only the action with the default values

Comment: Could you share the code of the effect that is supposed to be called when the "Get user" action is dispatched ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun Doesn't matter, it isn't called. But is called on reload where i call it manually

Comment: @ibenjelloun Well i did it anyway xD

Comment: Last dumb question, is the `"GetUser"` type equal to `"[USER] Get user"` ? The `"[USER] Google Login"` has a capital lettre on the "L", maybe the type is `"[USER] Get User"`.

Comment: Yes, the naming doesn't matter i thnk. I have a  const i am using anyway: `export const GET_USER             = '[USER] Get user';`

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one:

```
@Effect()
googleLogin: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(

        ofType(UserActions.GOOGLE_LOGIN),
        map(action => action.payload), // if there is no payload disregard this
        exhaustMap((auth: any) => Observable.fromPromise(this.loginWithGoogle()
               .pipe(
                  map(() => new UserActions.GetUser()),
                  catchError(err => Observable.of(new UserActions.AuthError({error: err.message})))
            ))
        )

    )
```

for this a little difference between exhaustMap and switchMap.
let me know if you succeed to work it.

Comment: also, this is a nice explanation regarding exhaustMap and switchMap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49698640/flatmap-mergemap-switchmap-and-concatmap-in-rxjs/49723075#49723075

Comment: Unfortunately no, no effect at all. Still the same behaviour as before.

Comment: Are you sure loginWithGoogle returns a promise? you can return from loginWithGoogle as observable and get rid of observable.fromPromise().  maybe something shady happens in there. if you resolve the problem please let me know how. good luck

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one? It might help in my opinion.

```
  @Effect()
  googleLogin = this.actions.ofType(UserAction.GOOGLE_LOGIN).pipe(
    map(() => Observable.fromPromise(this.loginWithGoogle()),
    mergeMap(()=> return[{type: UserActions.GET_USER}])
  );
```

Comment: This one doesn't call the effect at all

Comment: @PsychoPflanze WATMAN, it's really strange

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, I think the effect is not being called because in your `getUser` effect you are not implementing `catch` block if the effect throws any error, so ideally in this case if an effect gets an error and it doesn't have any catch mechanism the effect won't invoke for further actions.

Comment: But i have a catch function in `getUser`, and it doesn't get called.

Comment: `@Effect()
    getSearchData: Observable<Action|any> = this.actions
    .ofType()
    .map()
    .switchMap()
      .mergeMap(result => {
        return [];
      })
      .catch(e => Observable.of(new actions.ApiError(e)))
    );`

Usually, this is how u frame my effects to get them invoked multiple times,  if you keep the catch block outside again it won't work for multiple actions.

Comment: My `getUser` effect is built exactly like that, but it somehow breaks with `signInWithPopup`

Comment: strange, @PsychoPflanze is it fixed now, are you still facing the same.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. I am thinking about making my own backend