# How to dispatch multiple actions in ngrx/effect (redux-observable)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using Angular 6, ngrx/store. I have such effect that is responsible for updating things. Depends on some logic I want to dispatch different actions. What is the difference if I use `switchMap` insted of `map`?

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
 @Effect()
  dispathMultipleActions$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.UpdateSomething),
    map(() => {
      const actions: Action[] = [];
      const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      array.forEach(item => {
        if (item > 3) {
          actions.push(new DeleteAction(item));
        } else {
          actions.push(new ChangeAction(item));
        }
      });
      return actions;
    })
  );
```

Comment: I think you want to try switchMap with a function that returns an Observable.concat of the inner actions. This will flatten the list of actions and take order into account.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An effect transforms a stream of actions, so you have a stream of actions as input and output. In your example, you map an action to an **array of actions**. A stream of arrays of actions is not a valid output type. You need to flatten that array, meaning that you do not emit the array itself into the output stream but instead each of its elements.

Instead of:

```
input:  --a-------a------>
output: --[b,c]---[b,c]-->
```

You should do:

```
input:  --a-------a------>
output: --b-c-----b-c-->
```

For flattening an Observable of array into Observables of each element, you can use one of the operators `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `exhaustMap`. In most cases, `mergeMap` will be the right choice. If you want to learn more about these operators, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49723075/4694994).

```
@Effect()
register$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_REQUEST),
  mergeMap((action: RegisterRequest) => {
    // check for register request success
    return [
      new RegisterSuccess(),
      new LoginRequest(action.payload)
    ]
  })
);
```

Comment: Hello,
it seems that it no longer works with NGRX 10: 

as soon as I put an array to return 2 actions (which work alone), I have a TS error saying the type []is incompatible with an 'Action'...

Comment: To complete my comment: the solution seems to be:  ` this.store$.dispatch(RegisterSuccess());   return LoginRequest(action.payload);

Comment: Can you pls clarify - why array of actions is considered to be an array of observables in this case ? Action != Observable. Though i also use this pattern and it works as expected

Answer (score 5):

I have had same situation (and assuming NgRx 10 or higher), I have a different perspective, more fundamental way how to use effects. Triggering sequentially  multiple actions in one place, specially within a single effect, is anti-pattern.
In essense, its important to keep a consistent [general flow of application state in NgRx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store#diagram) of actions and potentials reductions. Just as the NgRx architecture  foresees it.

Following [the 3 effect rules](https://dev.to/davidshortman/3-radically-small-things-you-can-change-in-your-ngrx-effects-code-that-will-make-me-sleep-better-tonight-21id) will help already to avoid difficult situations:

1. Name effects to be the name of the effect
2. Make your effect only do one thing
3. Emit only one action

That way, it helps you to follow the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design pattern which of course also help you the NgRx effects to become a lot more unit testable.

Back to your example, you can simple decouple what you wanted to do (2 additional actions) with an in-between-proxy action.

In your case it seems that you may not need even your original effect *dispathMultipleActions$*, unless special logic within appears. (which perhaps, may belong into a state Reducer, which is even more unit testable).

Assuming that the ActionTypes.UpdateSomething has a array payload object already, you could split your *dispathMultipleActions$* into single ones, so you could do something like this:

```
@Effect()
deleteAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.UpdateSomething),
    concatMap(from(new Promise((array) => {
        array.forEach(item => {
            if (item > 3) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    }))),
    {dispatch: false}
);

@Effect()
changeAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.UpdateSomething),
    concatMap(from(new Promise((array) => {
        array.forEach(item => {
            if (item <= 3) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    }))),
    {dispatch: false}
);
```