# Rxjs Combine dynamic amount of observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am creating a loader for [@ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), that loads multiple JSON translation files from a directory based on the selected language.

The way I am currently loading the files is via an `index.json` file that contains an array with names and extensions for the translation files for that language.

The structure of the translation files is as follows:

```
- assets
  - i18n
    - index.json <-- Contains an array of translation file names
    - en_US
      - home.json
      - header.json
    - de_DE
      - home.json
      - header.json
```

An example of the `index.json` is as follows:

```
[
  "home.json",
  "header.json"
]
```

Since the Angular `HttpClientModule` cannot load the contents of a directory or the names of files in a directory (it can only load single json files) I need to define the names in the `index.json`.

This also means I have to first load the index.json and then load all the other files in the directory.

In code this means the following:

1. Load the index.json
2. Loop over the array of file names
3. Load every file in a separate request
4. When all finished combine all the file contents into one object

---

**What I've tried**

```
 public getTranslation(language: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getIndexFile(language)
      .pipe(
        map((fileNames: string[]) => {
          const promises = [];

          for (const name of fileNames) {
            const path = Translation.replaceUrlPlaceholder(this.path, language);
            promises.push(this.http.get(path + '/' + name + '.json').toPromise());
          }

          return Promise.all(promises);
        }),
      );
  }
```

So I've tried this with promises, but this obviously doesn't work (since an observable must be returned). Also the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593900/rxjs-one-observable-feeding-into-another) doesn't work for me, since I need to dynamicatlly create an unlimited amount of observables and wait for them to finish before I can start on step **4.** (combine all files).

What should be the correct way to do this?

---

- Angular `7.1.0`
- RxJS `6.3.3`
- @ngx-translate/core `11.0.1`

---

**Update**

Stackblitz here: [Combining observables](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtdyfc)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: @trichetriche, updated with more detailed information. Are you missing anything or does this meet the rules of a stackoverflow post? :)

Comment: Well a sandbox on https://stackblitz.com would be the best, as it would allow us to simply implement the solutions we offer you.

Comment: @trichetriche, added a stackblitz that is reproducing my problem.

Comment: Sorry, was working on the side. I have [made a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv4tha?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with clear separation of functions and their usage, feel free to check it out !

Comment: Thanks for the stackblitz! I see that I was on the right track (see my answer), but needed to do some more separation like you did. Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Nah don't worry about that, wait 3 days and mark your own as the one, and use my stackblitz if you want. I'm here to help as much people has I can, but this issue was only for you, as it's just the syntax you didn't quite get. And if you can't see it, I don't really need the reputation, so take advantage of it to gain some :) good luck with your project !

Comment: I'l then mark mine as the correct answer, but I've added your answer as an improvement on mine. And thanks, this problem was quite a pain in the ass.

Comment: I can feel your pain, I had the same kind of issues when I started. To get a better grip of the concept, I looked at [all operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) and their marble diagrams, to see what they were doing. If I can advise you one thing to understand all of this faster, is to manage all of your variables through observables and `async` pipes. You'll be forced to learn operators and their syntax this way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after searching and trying some more I found the solution to my answer. There where 2 problems:

**1. Flatmap vs Map**

I was using a `map()` instead of a `flatMap`. The difference is that the flatMap will execute when the first observable has finished. This way the subscribe won't get the result until the flatMap observable has finished.

**2. Promise.all vs forkJoin**

The observable equivalent of `Promise.all()` is `forkJoin()`. ForkJoin wil execute all observables in parallel and returns the result of all observables in one array.

---

**The result**

So updating the code above will result in the following stackblitz: [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zttuxq)

Or in code:

```
  public getTranslation(language: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getIndexFile(language)
      .pipe(
        flatMap((fileNames: string[]) => {
          const observables: Observable<any>[] = [];

          for (const name of fileNames) {
            const path = 'assets/i18n/' + language + '/' + name + '.json';
            observables.push(this.http.get(path));
          }

          // Run all the observables in parallel
          return forkJoin(observables);
        }),
      );
```

---

**Separation of Concern**

My code contains multiple actions in one function which make it hard to test. So that should be separated. @trichetriche made a version which includes separation of concern.

See his Stackblitz for the code: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv4tha?file=src/app/app.component.ts)